# Laravel - How can I avoid users to see content not owned by them (and relations)

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, relationship

In a Laravel 5.1 project I have:

**Videos** that belong to **Pages** and **Pages** that belongs to **Users**.
I want to make sure Users can't Videos and Pages not owned by them. Admin users can see all Pages and Videos.

How to solve this?

*I am already using a middleware and passing User ID as a parameter, but I don't know how to get the User ID inside the Video Constructor.
I probably need something like [Constructor Injection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers), but the documentation is not really clear.*

---

***EDIT:***
As recommended by @tommy I used Laravel authorization to check if user had permission or not.
I decided to use a single repository, since the check would always to be the same (matching pages with user)

**In \App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider**

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);

    $gate->define('check-owner', function ($user, $page) {
        return $user->id === $page->user_id;
    });
}
```

**In App\Repositories\OwnerRepository**

```
namespace App\Repositories
use App\Page;
use Gate;
   class OwnerRepository
   {
      public function CheckifOwns(Page $page){
         if (Gate::denies('check-owner', $page)) 
         {
           abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
         }
      }
   }
```

**In Videos Controller**

```
use App\Repositories\OwnerRepository;
private $repository;

public function __construct(OwnerRepository $repository)
{
    $this->repository = $repository;
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

---

```
public function show($id)
{
    $video= Video::findOrFail($id);
    $this->repository->CheckifOwns($video->Page);
    return view('videos.view',compact('video'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new Authorization system has been introduced with Laravel 5.1.11. You can use [Policies](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#writing-policies) to easily check if a user is allowed to access a specific resource:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization

Comment: thank for you quick reply!! I had a quick look and that seems exactly what I need!!! Will be back with updates! Cheers!

Comment: If you can have a look @tommy I edited the question with my solution, feel free to tell me what you think! And thanks again! ;)

Comment: Looks good, except you check for the ownership in the repository. The repository shouldn't be responsible for that. You can do it directly in the controller ;-)